# Error while installing tiff-3.8.2

Tags: libtiff

```
pranav@pranav-Inspiron-1545:~/dependency/tiff-3.8.2$ make
Making all in port
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/pranav/dependency/tiff-3.8.2/port'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/pranav/dependency/tiff-3.8.2/port'
Making all in libtiff
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/pranav/dependency/tiff-3.8.2/libtiff'
make  all-am
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/pranav/dependency/tiff-3.8.2/libtiff'
if /bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I. -I.     -g -O2 -Wall -W -MT tif_jpeg.lo -MD -MP -MF ".deps/tif_jpeg.Tpo" -c -o tif_jpeg.lo tif_jpeg.c; \
    then mv -f ".deps/tif_jpeg.Tpo" ".deps/tif_jpeg.Plo"; else rm -f ".deps/tif_jpeg.Tpo"; exit 1; fi
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I. -I. -g -O2 -Wall -W -MT tif_jpeg.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/tif_jpeg.Tpo -c tif_jpeg.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/tif_jpeg.o
In file included from /usr/local/include/jpeglib.h:27:0,
                 from tif_jpeg.c:87:
/usr/local/include/jmorecfg.h:263:16: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
tif_jpeg.c: In function 'JPEGVSetField':
tif_jpeg.c:1578:8: warning: suggest braces around empty body in an 'if' statement [-Wempty-body]
make[2]: *** [tif_jpeg.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/pranav/dependency/tiff-3.8.2/libtiff'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/pranav/dependency/tiff-3.8.2/libtiff'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: by the way why INSTALL??

Answer (score 17):

Edit file: `/usr/local/include/jmorecfg.h`

change line:

```
typedef enum { FALSE = 0 , TRUE = 1 } boolean;
```

to:

```
typedef enum { false= 0 , true= 1 } boolean;
```

Then, make successful.

Answer (score 0):

I met this error when I compile for install emacs, and I don't think this is a perfect solution, my solution is change the source file which called jpeglib.h, before change:

```
# include <jpeglib.h>
```

after:

```
#define HAVE_BOOLEAN
typedef unsigned char boolean;
# include <jpeglib.h>
#undef HAVE_BOOLEAN
```

this solution work fine.